# How many days before an invoice is due does the invoice.upcoming webhook get called?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

The Stripe docs are really ambiguous about this:

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/webhooks

> A *few days* prior to renewal, your site receives an invoice.upcoming event at the webhook endpoint. You can listen for this event to add extra invoice items to a subscription draft invoice.

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle

> When the subscription *approaches its renewal date*, an invoice.upcoming event is sent.

---

Does anyone know roughly how much time is in between the `invoice.upcoming` webhook and the actual invoice?  A "few" days could be anywhere between 2-5 depending on who you ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the ability to set when `invoice.upcoming` will be sent in your [billing settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/billing/automatic).

[image: stripe billing settings]